# Dip switch or rolling code garage door opener?

Tags: rf, radio

I'm a total noob in electronics field and want to begin. (I'm an IT engineer).
I'm trying to use my remote garage door opener (868 MHz HF) to create a system with my Raspberry Pi so I can replicate the signal when I use an Android application (by contacting a web server on my Raspberry).
I did some research and found there are two different remotes: DIP switch ones and ones with rolling code where we can't replicate the signal as the code is changing every time.
I opened my remote to check and as I'm a total noob, I don't really know how to know which system it's using.
[image: remote]

Is it easy to replicate?

Comment: Dip switch is insecure. Rolling code is secure by 2step learning and is as secure as the protection of the original FOB or remote from loss or theft. The lack of DIP switch is your “tell” Nothing is easy unless you understand how it works.

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?client=safari&hl=en-ca&biw=320&bih=454&ei=LAoHW5KGNee3jwSz9L2IAQ&q=pic12lf1840t39a+rolling+code&oq=pic12lf1840t39a+rolling+code&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.3..33i160.11953.17149..18069...0....176.1214.11j2......0....1.........0i30j0i22i30j33i21.ewIBYeyRVvs%3D

Comment: I'd suggest that you may be better off putting some kind of relay/automation hat on your Pi and wiring it directly to your garage door opener as if it were a manual wall switch. Bypass the RF remote entirely.

Comment: It depends how secure you want your home. I leave my door open all the time, but then I’m not in the “excited states.” Plus we have a dog who makes an effective door bell.

Comment: Get an SDR and hack the rolling codes

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty confident that it's of the "rolling code" variety with strong encryption, so replicating it isn't feasible.

I suspect (based on the Microchip logo, pinout and TSSOP-14 package) that it uses this specific chip: "[MCS3122](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001762A.pdf) Advanced [KEELOQ®](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KeeLoq) Technology Encoder", just with a different part number on the manufacturer's request.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I need to find another system then. Maybe emulate the button by using some wires linked to the raspberry.